# Reattach armature to parts of mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, pose-mode, vertex-weights

I created a body with Human Generator and a head with Face Builder and then replaced the HG head with the one from Face Builder. Now, obviously the armature in the head area is not working anymore but when I try parenting with automatic weights I get an error stating that it fails to find solution for some bones. Is there a way to use the existing armature in this case and have the new head work as if it was part of the HG generated mesh? The end purpose is to be able to pose the body and face expression but no animation. This will be part of a more complex interior setup with three characters, furniture, clothes etc. It all remains in Blender so I won't need to export anywhere.
I attached the file for reference.
I would be grateful for any idea or even a completely different workflow than the one I started with. I'm in the process of learning but I also need this for a client and I am looking to establish a good workflow for this kind of combination for use in future similar projects.

[image]

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wrOTMnbi-2k9wNd6bsbB-rsIIB5Gc3bx/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: you have a lot of bones for the eyes, eyelids, mouth, etc, do you plan to use them?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't plan to use all the head bones like eyes, eyelids, mouth, etc, remove them in *Edit* mode:

[image]

Also join the teeth and eye objects to the head object. Then select the armature in *Object* mode, shift select the character object, switch it to *Weight Paint* mode, left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> left click on the head bone, deactivate the *Front Faces Only* option and activate the *Projected* option, and paint the head. Do the same for the neck bone:

[image]

In the modifier stack, put the *Armature* at the top so that the particle systems follow when you animate the head:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @moonboots, It would be simpler indeed not to use the face bones. I would  need though to pose it with different facial expressions at a certain point. But your answer is very useful already! Extrapolating from your solution, is it possible to paint areas of the face for at least a few of the face bones to be able to give him a bit of smile ? I will edit the eye area as well to have the eyes (different objects) posable.   Also, after I do the last step of your solution I suppose I need to do the automatic weights...?

Comment: You don't need to parent With Automatic Weights. For the small facial bones, you'll need to paint the influence for each one, but for the eye balls for example, select the vertex group to which they are supposed to be part of in the Vertex Group list and click on the Assign button under this list

Comment: Thank you! I’ll get to work.